# meaning of 'inspire' in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you take a look at this sentence?
I'm not sure if I get the meaning of the sentence correctly.

```
**The project inspires children with dreams.**
```

I think it means 1. 'The project inspires children to have dreams'. or 2.'The project inspires children by giving dreams.'

If none of them is correct, could you paraphrase this sentence?

Comment: Or perhaps 3. "This project inspires those children who dream."

Comment: Or perhaps "This project inspires children to dream".

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to interpret the claim. Consider interpreting the expression *with* the following definitions:

> **with** *preposition*
> 3 Indicating the instrument used to perform an action.
> ‘cut it with a knife’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/with)
>
> **dream** *noun*
> 2 A cherished aspiration, ambition, or ideal.
> ‘I fulfilled a childhood dream when I became champion’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dream)

The claim is then that the project inspires children by using positive examples that the children can aspire to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your explanation ,which includes the definitions of each word, helped me understand better.

Comment: @tammy You're welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is quite strange to me, like basically you could paraphrase that sentence rather than making fixed sentence like that. Doing so will help you tell more or even make it a little bit exaggerating. It would be **The project has inspired children to have dreams or start thinking of dreams**. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are too many completely different connotations to this sentence. Is it a disconnected slogan, or motto, being used by some service organization somewhere? Just by itself, *'children with dreams'* is very awkward. All children envision a future with aspirations and dreams (hopefully positive ones).